# inverse and derivative of a third order polynomial

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, inverse-function

first of all, excuse me for my English

I must calculate the inverse function of
$$f(x)=-x^3-x+6$$
and then the derivative. my problem isn't the derivative, my problem is that I just can't calculate the inverse for third order polynomials.

I begin by doing the following:

$y=f(x)=-x^3-x+6 \rightarrow y-6=-x^3-x \rightarrow -y+6=x^3+x$

and then I just don't know what to do

thank you for the help

Comment: En inglés, la palabra que desea es "degree," no "grade." Also, Wolfram doesn't give a particularly nice-looking inverse: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+function+f%28x%29+%3D+-x%5E3+-+x+%2B+6

Comment: @SeanRoberson I edited the question and waiting to get it accepted the OP doesn't need to do anything ;)

Comment: Note that, as always, you can implicitly compute the derivative of the inverse without computing the inverse itself: the chain rule gives you $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} = \dfrac1{-3x^2 - 1}$.  But that may not be what's meant in the context (so can you say more about the context?).

Comment: thanks for the help whit the formal lenguage. about what i have to do i must find the tangent that touch the function in an especific point on the inverse of the function and i dont know if i can do it whitout the inverse but i really want to compute it.

Comment: para el compa que habla español, argentina campeon del mundo papaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cubic equation
$$-x^3-x+(6-y)=0$$ Its discriminant
$$\Delta=-27 (y-6)^2-4$$ is negative for all $y$; then, only one real root and you can compute its inverse.

Using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root)
$$x=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\,\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}    (y-6)\right)\right)$$ looks pretty nice